# If Flow in Amazon Connect has Start Media Streaming Block, but no corresponding Stop, will live audio stream be demarcated accurately?

Tags: amazon-connect, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

My contact Flow in Amazon Connect has a `Start Media Streaming` block, but no corresponding `Stop Media Streaming`.  In my Amazon Connect dashboard, I have not enabled Data Streaming, and therefore, the software module that picks up the live audio stream (through Kinesis Video Streams) is not also picking up Agent Events.

Question:  in the absence of Agent Events that might demarcate the live audio stream, and in the absence of a `Stop Media Streaming` block in the contact Flow, can we expect the live audio stream to be properly demarcated by the beginning / end of the call?

My logic for ingesting the live audio stream, shown in a [separate article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76910869/why-is-live-audio-extracted-from-amazon-connect-through-kinesis-video-stream-noi), just assumes the end of the live audio stream will be demarcated by the absence of new audio chunks over the stream.  But is that accurate?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/start-media-streaming.html) : "You must use a Stop media streaming block to stop media streaming."

Comment: How do you add a `Stop Media Streaming` in the contact Flow to indicate it happens at the end of the agent-caller engagement?

Comment: Before streaming, you'd notify the caller to press a key to end the recording. That way after the Start streaming block you can use Get Customer Input to listen for that key and on success you stop media streaming. With Get Customer input you can also configure a timeout, which is nice for situations like this.